# Mysteriously losing reputation

Tags: bug, reputation

I haven't been down-voting, nor have I received any notification of a down-vote or *user removed*. But somehow over the last week I've lost about 20 rep. And I've done nothing. What's happening?

Comment: should we remove the "bug" tag (and replace it by "status: by design" or something like that)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know how your [reputation tab](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/142799/kunal-pawar?tab=reputation&sort=time) looks to you, since you don't have [the privilege of viewing deleted posts](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools), but it looks like you earned several +2 rep points for [suggesting edits](https://physics.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits) to posts which were later deleted.
You may or may not be able to see these examples:
[for instance](https://physics.stackexchange.com/revisions/334473/2), [for instance](https://physics.stackexchange.com/revisions/334541/2), [for instance](https://physics.stackexchange.com/revisions/333910/2).

Most reputation changes associated with a post are un-done if that post is deleted. Nothing wrong on your end --- thanks for working to make the site more readable.

Comment: Nope. Unable to see a single example. Nevertheless, it turned out to be exactly what I suspected. Many thanks for the answer.

Comment: I feel like that's a flaw in the system... If an edit is made and accepted, that's kind of a "done deal" -- regardless of what happens to the post in question. It was made in good faith and approved. We don't give rep or take away rep when the edited question is up or down voted, nor do I think rep should be removed for edits that were accepted if the post ends up deleted. But, that's just my two cents. I'm not fired up enough about it to start a whole mother meta conversation (which may already exist, I didn't look).